# Why the "-" in "ex-pat" sometimes?

Tags: etymology

While "expat" and "expatriate" are commonly used, I also often see "ex-pat" in news articles:

- [So You Think You Can Be An Ex-Pat?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/shelliekarabell/2017/09/24/so-you-think-you-can-be-an-ex-pat-check-out-this-report) Forbes
- [Australian ex-pat writer and TV critic Clive James dead at 80](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/culture/2019/11/28/entertainment-news/australian-ex-pat-writer-tv-critic-clive-james-dead-80) Japan Times via Reuters

What is the origin of "-" between "ex" and "pat"?

Note: When I copy/paste this character from the Forbes article into Wikipedia, I am redirected to [Hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being the short for [expatriate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expatriate), [expat](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expat) is the correct spelling, without hyphen as suggested in all online dictionaries.  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expat%2Cex-pat%2C%20ex%20pat&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cex%20-%20pat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cex%20pat%3B%2Cc0) shows  few usage instances of the hyphenated form which is a “nonstandard” variant, probably  influenced by the usage of the prefix [ex-](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ex-) in terms like ex-president, [ex-wife](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ex-wife) etc.

Comment: You should reverse the order of your answer to improve the quality (your second sentence more directly answers the question asked), and substitute `accepted` for the word `correct`. A simple [Twitter search](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22ex-pat%22&src=typed_query) shows ample usage of `ex-pat`; back-formations are ubiquitous in English.

Comment: @MichaelChirico - In my answer I express the concept you are referring to in the “nonstandard variant” definition.

Comment: @user067531 yes, that's fine, but your first sentence still refers to the `correct` spelling

Comment: @MichaelChirico - expat is the correct original spelling, ex-pat is a nonstandard variant which is also used.

Answer (score 1):

“*Expatriate*” is one word. “*Ex-patriate*” doesn’t work, because the prefix “*ex*-” with a hyphen carries the meaning of “used to be,” as in “*ex-president*”, “*ex-linebacker*”, or “*ex-priest*”. For the same reason, the colloquial short form “*expat*” is correct, not “*ex-pat*”.

Many people misspell “*expatriate*” as “*ex-patriot*” (mainly because the pronunciation is near-identical). An ‘*ex-patriot*’ literally means a former patriot — a potentially costly mistake if used to refer to an expatriate (because it’s potentially defamatory then).

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expat%2C+ex-pat&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cex%20-%20pat%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cexpat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cex%20-%20pat%3B%2Cc0), “*expat*” seems to be used as far back as the 1800s, whereas “*ex-pat*” came into use after the 1950s.

> [image]

Comment: Former Patriots include Nathan Hale and Tom Brady.

Comment: Julia Sweeny is an ex-Pat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Pat